# How to use Fancybox in a polymer paper-card

Tags: html, css, polymer, fancybox

I have a list of **paper-card** and I want to know how to use the **fancybox** library to preview the card content of my **paper-card**.

Here is an example of **paper-card**:

```
<paper-card heading="Emmental" 
    image="http://placehold.it/350x150/FFC107/000000" alt="Emmental">
    <div class="card-content">
        Emmentaler or Emmental is a yellow, medium-hard cheese that originated in the area around Emmental, Switzerland. It is one 
        of the cheeses of Switzerland and is sometimes known as Swiss 
        cheese.
    </div>
    <div class="card-actions">
        <paper-button>Share</paper-button>
        <paper-button>Explore!</paper-button>
    </div>
</paper-card>
```

Comment: I did not use fancybox before, but it looks like it's built with jQuery.. and if so, chances are it won't work with Polymer.. that's because as soon as you write something like `$(some-selector-here)`, you are basically doing something like `document.querySelectorAll(some-selector-here)`, and this won't work with shadow DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`fancybox`](https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/) with Polymer by passing the `<paper-card>` reference (via `this.shadowRoot.querySelector()` to jQuery:

```
firstUpdated() { // LitElement callback: element has rendered
  const card = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.card');
  $(card).fancybox();
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- Polyfills only needed for Firefox and Edge. -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs@latest/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.4.2/jquery.fancybox.min.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.4.2/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Works only on browsers that support Javascript modules like
Chrome, Safari, Firefox 60, Edge 17 -->
    <script type="module">
      import {LitElement, html} from 'https://unpkg.com/@polymer/lit-element/lit-element.js?module';
      import 'https://unpkg.com/@polymer/paper-card/paper-card.js?module';
      import 'https://unpkg.com/@polymer/paper-button/paper-button.js?module';

      class MyElement extends LitElement {
        render() {
          return html`
            <style>
              .card {
                width: 300px;
              }
            </style>
            <paper-card class="card"
                data-fancybox
                data-animation-effect="false"
                href="https://placehold.it/350x150/FFC107/000000"
                heading="Emmental" 
                image="https://placehold.it/350x150/FFC107/000000" alt="Emmental">
                <div class="card-content">
                    Emmentaler or Emmental is a yellow, medium-hard cheese that originated in the area around Emmental, Switzerland. It is one 
                    of the cheeses of Switzerland and is sometimes known as Swiss 
                    cheese.
                </div>
                <div class="card-actions">
                    <paper-button>Share</paper-button>
                    <paper-button>Explore!</paper-button>
                </div>
            </paper-card>`;
        }
        
        firstUpdated() {
          const card = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.card');
          $(card).fancybox();
        }
      }

      customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
    </script>

    <my-element></my-element>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @DannickMontanede No problem :)